# Single Event Php Script

Tags: php, wordpress, events

I'm building a form that a cashier will enter a dollar amount into. When they enter that dollar amount it will add 100 points to their account for every dollar spent. This is built on WordPress so you'll see I'm getting and updating this point value with update_user_meta(); and get_user_meta(); which are built into WordPress.

You'll see I have a bunch of if statements that fire when the user hits the different point levels. My question is how can I make those statements only appear the very first time they've gone over the point threshold?

```
<form method="post" action="">
$<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$prev_total = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), mycred_default, true);
$add_total = (floor($_POST['value']) * 100);

$now_total = $prev_total + $add_total;
update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), mycred_default, $now_total);
echo get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), mycred_default, true);

if($now_total > 0 && $now_total < 2501){

    echo "<h2>Customer Get's A Free Small Cup or Cone of Custard: Next Level 5000 Points.</h2>";

} elseif($now_total > 4999 && $now_total < 7500){

    echo "<h2>Customer Get's A Free Medium Gelato: Next Level 7500 Points.</h2>";

} elseif($now_total > 7499 && $now_total < 10000){

    echo "<h2>Customer Get's A Free Brownie Blackout: Next Level 10,000 Points.</h2>";

} elseif($now_total > 9999 && $now_total < 15000){

    echo "<h2>Customer Get's A Free Large Milk Shake: Next Level 15,000 Points.</h2>";

} elseif($now_total > 14999 && $now_total < 20000){

    echo "<h2>Customer Get's A Free Pint of Custard: Next Level 20,000 Points.</h2>";

} elseif($now_total > 19999 && $now_total < 25000){

    echo "<h2>Customer Get's A Free Pint of Custard: Next Level 25,000 Points.</h2>";

} elseif($now_total > 24999 && $now_total < 35000){

    echo "<h2>Customer Get's A Free Round of Mini Golf: Next Level 35,000 Points.</h2>";

} elseif($now_total > 34999 && $now_total < 45000){

    echo "<h2>Customer Get's A Free Small Custard Cake: Next Level 45,000 Points.</h2>";

} elseif($now_total > 44999 && $now_total < 50000){

    echo "<h2>Customer Get's 20 Free Batting Cage Tokens: Next Level 50,000 Points.</h2>";

} elseif($now_total >= 50000){

    echo "<h2>Customer Get's 20 Free Batting Cage Tokens & 20 Free Batting Cage Tokens.</h2>";
    $now_total = 0;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your existing code I would add another condition to the `elseif`'s to check the previous total - something like

```
} elseif($prev_total < 5000 && $now_total > 4999 && $now_total < 7500){
```

So the next time they make a purchase the previous total value would be within these limits so it shouldn't hit until the next one.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try that out now!

Comment: Worked awesomely! Thanks for the help I appreciate it! Also for anyone who looks at this in the future the reason why in the last if statement I have $now_total = 0 is due to the fact that I want this rewards program to loop back through so customers start back at 0 again. This didn't work but I moved the update of user meta to the end and added another variable called $final_total = ($now_total < 49999 ? $now_total : 0); which then I put final total in the updated user meta as such update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), mycred_default, $final_total);